# where to download current composition of popular indexes?

Tags: data, spx, data-source, indexes

What are reliable sources to download plain-text files listing current composition of various popular indexes such as S&P 500 (SPX) or Dow Jones Industrials (DJI) or Nasdaq 100 (NDX) ?

At a minimum the file would include symbol, but hopefully name, sector, and other information.

The ideal format would be JSON , but XML or XLSX, but even simple formats such CSV or one symbol per line would be acceptable.

I've checked provider websites such as :

https://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-500

but no luck yet.

Comment: This is proprietary information, S&P etc. want you to pay for it. So it is not out there for everyone to find. There may be some underhanded ways of getting it but they should not be discussed here.

Comment: Ok that's fine. If we go the legit route how exactly to purchase the data ?  But wouldn't S&P want to provide the `SPX` and `DJI` components simply as a courtesy to seed the market for their other products ?  How can academic institutions get this data ?  What about independent software developers ?  It seems unreasonable for this only to be included in institutional subscriptions.

Answer (score 4):

This site has the company name, symbol, and index weight of all 3 indexes you are asking about.  The data is not downloadable, however, simply copying and pasting the data from the page into a spreadsheet works as does scraping the page.

[SlickCharts.com](https://www.slickcharts.com/)

Comment: Useful site, let's hope it lasts...

Answer (score 2):

I created a site to collect some useful macro financial indicators and hopeful can continue adding more data in my spare time.

Hopefully it can help you: https://datamatrixweb.com/